# Stop UI Alert Controller going back to previous view

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a UIAlertView within my app. But for some strange reason if I decide to press the "Back" button on the Alert View. It actually takes me to the previous view controller rather than simply dismissing the alert.

How can I prevent this? I only want to hid the alert if the back button is pressed

Video of the issue: https://youtu.be/fhb-REuQiyg

Here's the function for the alert:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Open Map", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Google Maps", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    self.googleMapsOpen()
}))
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Apple Maps", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    self.appleMapsOpen()
}))
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Back", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}))
self.present(alertController, animated: true) {
}
```

Comment: A button labeled "Back" *should* dismiss the current view controller. If you simply want to dismiss the alert, label it "Cancel" and don't dismiss the current view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Back", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) 
}))
```

the alert controller is dismissed automatically when you press the action , so your written dismiss will dismiss the current presented vc also

Comment: You should make it clear that `self` is the view controller, not the alert controller.

Comment: @rmaddy this isn't  the case as if the above line executed any how while the alert is presented , it will dismiss the alert not the vc controller , so self her runs in the current state of that vc

Comment: Huh? But the OP's problem is that calling `self.dismiss` is dismissing the view controller. That's because `self` is the view controller. Knowing that `self` is the view controller and not the alert is very relevant. And an alert action's handler is called *after* the alert has already been dismissed. And your answer is confusing because it appears you are suggesting that the `self.dismiss` line should be kept in the handler.